# Issue in scheduling a task in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to schedule a task to run a proc. I can create the task with the below code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK etl_monitoring_task_snowplow
  WAREHOUSE = PSS_RAJA
  SCHEDULE = '15 MINUTE'
  WHEN 
  system$stream_has_data('OOBE.information_schema.load_history')
```

But when I set it to run with the below query:

```
ALTER TASK etl_monitoring_task_snowplow RESUME;
```

I am getting the below error :

> Cannot execute task , EXECUTE TASK privilege must be granted to owner role

Answer (score 0):

SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA can only be used on a table stream. The error doesn't suggest this is an issue but either way I don't think it will work if pointing to a view in information_schema

Comment: I did remove the WHEN condition  but still same error

Comment: Try using the accountadmin role

Comment: Yes, I tried with SYSADMIN role but no luck

Comment: You'll need to request your ACCOUNTADMIN or SECURITYADMIN to grant the EXECUTE TASK privilege to the role you used to create the TASK as described by Mike Walton here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009PKc8QSAT/the-two-task-created-successfully-but-are-not-running